# Select InnerText of XML is decoding URL

Tags: c#, xml

My issue is, when selecting a node from xml file (packet in my case) is decoding an url that is the inner text of the node within the xml. Example

```
<url>"http://my.xml.org/?id=AAA%2DDDD%3dNNNLKLKJLKL%2"</url>
```

using an instance of XmlDocument:

```
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("url").InnerText;
```

The string that is returned is: `"http://my.xml.org/?id=AAA/DDDD/NNNLKLKJLKL/"`

How do I prevent this from happening? Notice that the %2 and %3's have been changed to forward slashes.

Comment: can you show the full xml I am wondering if you have the `xml header defined incorrectly` for example should look like this in the first line of your xml file
`<?xml version="1.0"?>`

Comment: "when selecting a node from xml file (packet in my case) is decoding an url that is the inner text of the node within the xml." It doesn't do that. https://ideone.com/RqVogS Something else isn't working, but `XmlDocument` doesn't do anything. See the StdOut in the linked code snippet.

Comment: @MethodMan I'm not specifying a encoding on the xml tag ex.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <url>"http://my.xml.org/?id=AAA%2DDDD%3dNNNLKLKJLKL%2"</url>
</xml>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below gets correct results.  What are you doing differently?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
                "<url>\"http://my.xml.org/?id=AAA%2DDDD%3dNNNLKLKJLKL%2\"</url>";

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
            string results = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("url").InnerText;

        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: I'm doing just that lol. I found that, that wasn't the issue. So apparently my web service (WCF) call is decoding the url once it receives the xml packet. But I haven't figured out it's doing it or how to fix it.

Comment: I think I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler t verify the xml is being sent correctly.  what is the source of the xml?  Are you getting the closing tag?